# Cut your dress down to your length/size

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

A girl buys a size that fits her, but is too long for her. So she says:

> I guess I'll have to cut it down to my "**length/size"**. (It fits her perfectly but is too long)

So what should be used "length/size"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She would say "I'll have to cut it to the right **length**."

**Size** in clothing would be more likely to indicate that it's too big in terms of *width*.

Specifically in this case, she's more likely to say "It fits nicely, but I'll have to **hem** it" which means to cut or turn under the excess material and sew a new bottom edge.

If the length was right but the dress was too big or wide on her, she might say "The length is good, but I'll have to **take it in**," which means to remove excess fabric width-wise.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I would find either "This dress falls a little above/below the knee" perfectly fine, but "a lot" would sound strange to me. If you meant to just describe the length, I might expect "This dress falls at the mid-thigh" or "This is a mini-dress." Mid-calf is typically referred to as "midi" length, while longer, like ankle- or floor-length is sometimes called a "maxi dress." To express that the dress is too short, I'd just expect that in a sentence. Or, for emphasis, "This dress is way too short."

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I think I'd expect "far above/far below" instead of "much over/much below" in those examples, but I can't say why for sure.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I wouldn't say "over the knee" to mean "above the knee" because it could be confused for "below the knee." Often when we use "over" with clothes, we mean that the clothes cover that part of the body.

Comment: Hi Katy, sorry for this message ...... but can you please reply to this post : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209275/your-ponytail-is-off-to-one-side.   I didn't get any replies to it and you're a girl .....