# Your ponytail is off to one side

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Someone was **trying to make a ponytail**.  So by mistake that person **made it off to one side**,(**off-center** i.e.
 **not in the middle of the head**) ,will it be natural to say:

> I did my ponytail a little bit **on the side.**(the person who made it, said that)
>
> Your  ponytail is **on the side a bit**. (The other person comments on it).

*Or should it be:*

> I: "I did my ponytail a little bit **off to one side."**
>
> The other person: "Your ponytail is a little bit **off to one side".**

????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was **intentional**, I would expect "I did a side-ponytail," or "I did my ponytail to one side."

If it was a **mistake**, I would expect "Your ponytail is **off-center**," or "Your ponytail is **a little crooked**."

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yes, either "I did it to the left/right" or "I did it on the left/right" would sound natural to me. "Off to one side" is fine, but typically if it's intentional, the whole ponytail is just called a side-ponytail.

Comment: Hi Katy, Can you please answer this post:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212449/section-two-pieces-segments-of-hair-take-two-segments-of-hair-maybe-a-girl-can.                            Basically,  do "Take a small section of hair in the front" and "how to section your hair" sound natural?

Comment: Actually a lot of people said that " Section two roughly symmetrical pieces of hair" sounds unnatural,  though a lady wrote it on a website. (The first link....)

Comment: I am actually still confused. (And I want an American opinion on that) The first sentence was not liked by many but a native American used it. So do you find it unnatural as well? What might be used instead? [The sentence: Section two roughly symmetrical pieces of hair.