# Section two pieces, take two segments of hair

Tags: spoken-english

Will all the three sentences express this idea naturally?

[image]

> Section  two roughly symmetrical  pieces of your hair at the front. (Used by an American on a website.)

Or

> Take two sections of your hair at the front.

Do all of these sentences sound natural and likely to you????

And what about:

> Take a small section of hair in the front.

Here are a few links:
https://www.instructables.com/id/Two-Small-Braids/

https://oureverydaylife.com/small-single-braids-yourself-20372.html

https://www.byrdie.com/boxer-braids-tutorial

https://www.ouidad.com/blog/classic-02

So do those three sentences sound equally likely?

Comment: I might just call them ***lengths**,* but ***hanks, strands*** and ***locks*** would also be quite common (and more specific to "hair").

Comment: I think section here is fine. ***Divide something into sections***. English would allow for that. It's not academic writing...Merriam Webster: to cut or separate into sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "section" as a verb is unnatural in this context. I've certainly heard it in hair tutorials on youtube by plenty of different native speakers. 
Though I have heard it by itself, "**section off**" sounds more natural to my ear.

> "Section **off** two equal pieces of hair at the forehead/behind the ear/at the crown of the head."

That said, I think "section" is much more common **as a noun** in this context (ex: "Separate/divide your hair into three equal sections, and bring the first section over the second") so using it as a verb as well might sound a little strange because it's duplicative.

David Siegel's first three examples sound natural to me; the fourth one ("take a set of hair") sounds really off.

Comment: So is the use of "pieces" natural according to you? Does it sound like a single "cut off" hair strand?

Comment: And what do you think about :"Take two sections of hair in the front."

Comment: Pieces is natural in the context. I wouldn't necessarily use it to describe someone else's completed hairdo, but in instructions for creating a hairstyle, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I would say "take two sections of hair in front" is fluent enough, but not helpful as an initial instruction. I might expect it after a first instruction that says something like "Divide the hair into six sections, three on each side of the center part. Take the two sections of hair in front and..."

Comment: Does "pieces" sound like a "cut off" hair strand or just a small portion of hair ? And what sounds most likely to you "portion, "section" or "pieces"?

Comment: It depends on context. If someone said "She saw pieces of hair on the floor" it would sound cut off. If someone said "She had a piece of hair blowing into her face" I would think it was hair attached to her head. In the context of instructions, I wouldn't interpret it to mean "cut off."

Comment: I would say "portions" and "sections" are really good choices for written instructions or in conversation, while "pieces" is a little more informal.

Comment: I mean does it sound like a small portion of hair or a single hair strand?

Comment: So "pieces" will be more common in casual conversation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94261/discussion-between-its-about-english-and-katy).

Answer (score 1):

The first two sound very unnatural. I would not use the word "section" as a verb in this context.

I would say things such as:

> - Part the hair in the center.
> - Divide the hair into two sections.
> - Separate the hair into two sections (or parts).
> - Take a set of hair on one side, and ...

Comment: Some people say: How to section you hair?     Does taht sound unnatural as well?  And does the "third sentence" sound "natural"?

Comment: @It To me "How to section you hair? " does sound unnatural. When I hear "section" as a verb, i think "cut up" as in an autopsy or cutting an object apart. The 3rd sentence seems more natural to me, but I would prefer one of my examples. Mind you, the first two are not ungrammatical.

Comment: And what about: Take a small piece of hair.

Comment: @It's about English To me, "a small piece of hair" would suggest a strand cut off.

Comment: And do you think that there might be natives that use the verb form of "section "?

Comment: @It's about English I don't recall ever having heard it used in that sense, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Why have all the websites and videos used "how to section your hair?" Is that because it is short and it makes the title catchy? Or is it just poor English?

Comment: And what about: "Take two small portions of hair in the front?"

Comment: (The reason why I'm confused is that the first sentence was used by a native  American..) [the one you and many other find unnatural]

Comment: @It's about There is no "one true English". What one native speaker thinks good, another may think awkward or unnatural. I can only give my best opinion, backed by sources when possible.  And because there are other ways to use the word Ngrams does not help resolve this.

Comment: And is the use of "portions" natural according to you?

Comment: @it's about Yes, portions seems like a reasonable word for this meaning, to me.